# How to invoke same code using multiple events?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code ..

```
$("#input_name").blur(function(){
  //more code
});
```

It works fine, but now I need to invoke the same functionality as in the blur function above by clicking a button as well. Basically, I want to keep the blur as is, and add the onclick. Any ideas how do I do that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your function definition to not be inline and then reuse it.

```
function eventFunction(){
    //more code
}

$('#input_name').blur(eventFunction);
$('#button_name').click(eventFunction);
```

Comment: Any ideas how do I prevent default event? I know I can use event.preventDefault(); but not sure what is the best position to use it? Will it be ok inside eventFunction? I am not sure as I am using the blur as well ?

Comment: by passing in the event object to the function, you can manipulate it. function eventFunction(e){//code} you can call prevent default at any time, and if you want to keep the event from bubbling you can return false from your event function.

Comment: see @pointy's answer about the event type also. Then you can determine which parent function was called.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

```
$("#input_name").bind("blur click", function() { ... });
```

You can also separate the function definition from the binding:

```
function handler() { ... }

$('#input_name').blur(handler).click(handler);
```

Remember that jQuery will pass the event to the handler function, and you can check the event type:

```
function handler(ev) {
  if (ev.type === 'click') { ... }
```

Comment: Just a quick q - $('#input_name').blur(handler).click(handler); does this invoke the code twice??

Comment: That doesn't *invoke* the code at all - it has the same effect as calling "bind" once with both event names really.  Those functions *call* the already-bound handlers when you call them with no parameters, but when you pass in a function it just wires it up for future events. Make sense?

Comment: Hmm .. to be honest, it just went over the head. Anyway, I appreciate your help. Cheers.

Comment: Oh I just realised the bind above is for blur and click on the input itself .. actually my question was to have 2 different elements calling same function. and Joekari has answered it right

Comment: Well then if that's the case, you'd use the second approach. Declare the function, and then bind it to as many elements as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Place "//more code" in a function:

```
function more_code() {
    //more code
}
```

and call it from your handlers:

```
$("#input_name").blur(more_code)
```